# Is the pullback of differential geometry also a pull back in the sense of category theory?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory

I do think that the pullback of differential geometry is also a pullback in the sense of category theory, however I did have some trouble completely justifying this thought. This is were I got:

Lets consider a vector field $\eta : Y \rightarrow T(Y)$ and a diffeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$. Then from differential geometry the pullback can be written as,
$$ f^*(\eta)(x) = Tf^{-1}\circ \eta \circ f(x).$$

Thus the commutative diagram becomes:

[image: Commutative diagram]

Now since $Tf^{-1}$ is invertible, we can use $Tf$ to write commutative diagram as a fiber product. From category theory we can complete the diagram of the vector field $\eta: Y \rightarrow T(Y)$ and the tangent map $Tf: T(X)\rightarrow T(Y)$ to obtain

[image]

Now due to the uniqueness of the fiber product up to isomorphism we see that $Y \times_{T(Y)} T(X)$ equals $X$ . Also $\eta^*(Tf)$ should equal $f$ (up to isomorphism). But then $f^*\eta$ should equal $Tf^*\eta$, however the notation $f^*\eta$ does not make much sense to me, is this just a short hand? If this isn't the case can someone give me somewhat more information about $ f^*\eta$ in perspective of category theory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873460/is-there-a-relationship-between-the-pullback-in-differential-geometry-and-that-i?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way to think about this is that the answer to your question is **no**.  It may be possible to write the pullback of a vector field along a diffeomorphism as a pullback in the sense of category theory, but this is basically a coincidence and is not normally a helpful way to understand the concepts.

The word "pullback" is used very broadly to describe, well, pulling things back.  In other words, whenever you have a map $f:X\to Y$, and there is a natural way to turn some structure on $Y$ into a structure on $X$, you can describe that as a "pullback".  Pullbacks in the sense of category theory are one example of such a thing (where the structure on $Y$ is a map from some object to $Y$), and pullbacks of vector fields are another (where the structure on $Y$ is a vector field; notably, though, you can only perform such a pullback if $f$ is an open immersion).